# Не удается отправить файл на почту

Tags: php

Делаю отправку формы на почту с прикреплением файла. Письмо приходит без файла. Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в коде.

файл mailsend.php

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './php/vendor/autoload.php';
// Переменные, которые отправляет пользователь
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$file = $_FILES['userfile'];
$file_modal = $_FILES['userfile_modal'];
// Server side validation
function isValid() {
    // This is the most basic validation for demo purpose. Replace this with your own server side validation
    if($_POST['name'] != "" && $_POST['email'] != "" && $_POST['message'] != "") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$error_output = '';
$success_output = '';

if(isValid()) {
 //   Build POST request to get the reCAPTCHA v3 score from Google
    $recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $recaptcha_secret = '6Leoa68ZAdfkfdkfjJJKKFCDVKSOVDATb3Ba'; // Insert your secret key here
    $recaptcha_response = $_POST['recaptcha_response'];

    // Make and decode POST request
    $recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url . '?secret=' . $recaptcha_secret . '&response=' . $recaptcha_response);
    $recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha);
    // Take action based on the score returned
    if ($recaptcha->success == true && $recaptcha->score >= 0.5 && $recaptcha->action == 'contact') {
        // This is a human. Insert the message into database OR send a mail
        //send a mail
        // require_once "send.php";
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
try {
    $msg = "ok";
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.beget.ru';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'chesnokov@brelok.site'; // Ваш логин в Яндексе. Именно логин, без @yandex.ru
    $mail->Password = '111111111'; // Ваш пароль
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->setFrom('chesnokov@brelok.site'); // Ваш Email
    $mail->addAddress('chesnokov@brelok.site'); // Email получателя
        // // Прикрипление файлов к письму
        if (!empty($file['name'][0])) {
            for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($file['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
                $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($file['name'][$ct]));
                $filename = $file['name'][$ct];
                if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
                    $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
                    $rfile[] = "Файл $filename прикреплён";
                } else {
                    $rfile[] = "Не удалось прикрепить файл $filename";
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($file_modal['name'][0])) {
            for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($file_modal['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
                $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($file_modal['name'][$ct]));
                $filename = $file_modal['name'][$ct];
                if (move_uploaded_file($file_modal['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
                    $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
                    $rfile[] = "Файл $filename прикреплён";
                } else {
                    $rfile[] = "Не удалось прикрепить файл $filename";
                }
            }
        }

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Заявка с сайта';
    $mail->Body    =  "<b> Имя: </b> $name <br/><b>Телефон:</b> $phone <br/></b><b>Почта:</b> $email <br/><b>Текст письма:</b> $message";

// Проверяем отравленность сообщения
    if ($mail->send()) {
        $success_output = "Your message sent successfully";
        // echo "$msg";
    } else {
        $error_mail_output = "Сообщение не было отправленно, сервер не отвечает";
    }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Сообщение не было отправлено. Причина ошибки: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
    } else {
        // Server side validation failed
        $error_output = "Something went wrong. Please try again later";
    }
    }   else {
        $error_output = "Please fill all the required fields";
    }

    $output = array(
        'error'     =>  $error_output,
        'success'   =>  $success_output,
        'error_mail'   =>  $error_mail_output
    );

    // Output needs to be in JSON format
    echo json_encode($output);

    ?>
```

form.php

```
<form class="form row" id="form" type="submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form__background"></div>
  <h2 class="form__title text_title text_line col-lg-3">Оставьте заявку</h2>
  <div class="w-100"></div>
  <p class="form__comment text_main col-lg-7">и мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время. <br> Заполните опросный лист или оставьте контакты</p>
  <div class="w-100"></div><a class="text_link link_accent text_main col" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/files/Пример технического задания.docx" download="">Скачать опросный лист</a>
  <div class="w-100"></div>
  <div class="form__row col-lg-6">
    <input class="input form__input col form-control only_letters" placeholder="Имя*" name="name" required>
    <input class="input form__input col form-control only_number" id="phone1" placeholder="Телефон*" type="tel" minlength="11" maxlength="11" name="phone" required><span class="text_main form__error">Это поле должно содержать 11-ти значный номер телефона</span>
    <input class="input input__email form__input col form-control" id="inputEmail4" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required><span class="text_main form__error">Это поле должно содержать E-Mail в формате example@site.com</span>
    <div class="form__input form">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control control-checkbox text_main text_mini label_whithe">Согласие на обработку персональных данных
          <input class="control_indicator" type="checkbox" required>
          <div class="control_indicator"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form__row col-lg-6">
    <textarea class="input__comment form__textarea input form__input col form__input_big form-control" type="text" name="message" placeholder="Комментарий*"></textarea>
    <div class="input-file col text_main text_accent form__input input_accent">
      <input class="inputfile" id="userfile" type="file" name="userfile[]" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" accept="image/*">
      <label class="text_accent text_mini" for="userfile"><span>Прикрепить файл</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="alert" id="alert"></div>
    <input id="recaptchaResponse" type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response">
    <button class="button-send button-send_big form__button button-send_shadow col">Отправить заявку</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

файл form.js

```
$('#form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent direct form submission
    $('#alert').text('Processing...').fadeIn(0); // Display "Processing" to let the user know that the form is being submitted
    grecaptcha.ready(function () {
        console.log('i am redy ');
        grecaptcha.execute('6Leoa68ZAAAAAFhrhHXVIqwkRq9HMQ_acuTY9ZbG', { action: 'contact' }).then(function (token) {
            var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
            recaptchaResponse.value = token;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://prointechnology.ru/wp-content/themes/prointex/mailsend.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: $('#form').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function( _response ){
                    // The Ajax request is a success. _response is a JSON object
                    var error = _response.error;
                    var success = _response.success;
                    if(error != "") {
                        // In case of error, display it to user
                        $('#alert').html(error);
                    }
                    else {
                        $(".form").trigger("reset"); // очистка формы
                        $(".close").parents(".popup-fade");
                        $(".popup-fade").removeClass("popup-fade-show");
                        $(".popup-fade-secces").addClass("popup-fade-show");
                        // In case of success, display it to user and remove the submit button
                        $('#alert').html(success);
                        // $('#submit-button').remove();
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXhr, json, errorThrown){
                    // In case of Ajax error too, display the result
                    var error = jqXhr.responseText;
                    $('#alert').html(error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: А что у вас в $_FILES? multipart/form-data не забыли?

Comment: Исправил multipart/form-data добавил, в  $_FILES  <input class="inputfile" id="userfile" type="file" name="userfile[]" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple="" accept="image/*">  Но не отправляет все равно файл

Comment: Ну так сам массив $_FILES содержит данные? А то вы используете jquery serialize, а в доке к нему (https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) написано "Data from file select elements is not serialized.".

Comment: $_FILES  был пуст, использовал FormData() все заработало. Спасибо за поддержку